# R: refer to other DF by index within function

Tags: r, function, indexing, apply

I have a dataframe with row ID's and index values structured such as:

```
>DF
   ID asn bln gerp grn hgv hrn lwd mpl zwl
1  10   5   6    3   2  NA   4  NA  NA  NA
2  11  NA   3   NA  NA   4  NA  NA   5   6
3  12  NA  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA   4   3   2
4  13   3   2    5   6  NA   4  NA  NA  NA
5  14  NA  NA   NA  NA  NA  NA   2   3   4
```

And a timetbl:

```
>timetbl
  ID   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
1  10  900  910  920  930 1000
2  11  915  930 1000 1010 1020
3  12 1200 1230 1255   NA   NA
4  13 1640 1700 1710 1750 1800
5  14 2000 2100 2200   NA   NA
```

I need a function to create a new dataframe with the index numbers replaced by times from the timetbl DF, by using:

- `ID` for finding the right row
- the cell value as `index` to find the new value

Such that the result will be:

```
  ID  asn  bln gerp  grn  hgv  hrn  lwd  mpl  zwl
1  10  930 1000 910  900   NA  920   NA   NA   NA
2  11  915  930   NA   NA 1000   NA   NA 1010 1020
3  12   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 1255 1230 1200
4  13 1640 1700 1750 1800   NA 1710   NA   NA   NA
5  14   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 2000 2100 2200
```

I was trying to get the result by using `apply()`, `paste()` or the `%>%` but none was working out.

Any sugestions?

*Some data to try yourself:*

DF:

```
 > dput(DF)
    structure(list(ID = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14), asn = c(5L, NA, NA, 
3L, NA), bln = c(6L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA), gerp = c(3L, NA, NA, 5L, 
NA), grn = c(2L, NA, NA, 6L, NA), hgv = c(NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA), 
    hrn = c(4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA), lwd = c(NA, NA, 4L, NA, 2L), 
    mpl = c(NA, 5L, 3L, NA, 3L), zwl = c(NA, 6L, 2L, NA, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

timetbl:

```
    > dput(timetbl)
structure(list(ID = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14), X1 = c(900L, 915L, 
1200L, 1640L, 2000L), X2 = c(910L, 930L, 1230L, 1700L, 2100L), 
    X3 = c(920L, 1000L, 1255L, 1710L, 2200L), X4 = c(930L, 1010L, 
    NA, 1750L, NA), X5 = c(1000L, 1020L, NA, 1800L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at merge or join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't exactly match the output you give, but seems to match your description

```
id.match <- match(DF$ID, timetbl$ID) 

DF[-1] <- lapply(2:ncol(DF), function(x){
  timetbl[as.matrix(cbind(id.match, DF[x]))]
  })

DF
#   ID  asn  bln gerp  grn  hgv  hrn  lwd  mpl  zwl
# 1  1  930 1000  910  900   NA  920   NA   NA   NA
# 2  2   NA  930   NA   NA 1000   NA   NA 1010 1020
# 3  3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 1255 1230 1200
# 4  4 1700 1640 1750 1800   NA 1710   NA   NA   NA
# 5  5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 2000 2100 2200
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I made a typo in my question, R is always right ;-), furtermore, does this solution include the row ID?  The bigger DF I use skips some ID's, and the timetable has all ID's.

Comment: Yes it uses the ID column of DF to choose which row of timetbl to use, if that’s what you mean.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see indeed! It works perfectly for my smaller table but in the biger version (6306 x 681) I get the error:  `Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds.` The timetable has dimension 6306 x 59, and the same ID's..

Comment: probably some of your `DF` entries correspond to rows or columns in `timetbl` which don't exist

Comment: Hi Ryan, I discoverd that I get that error if the ID is higher than the number of columns in timetbl. I updated the dput() so you and/or others can try again. Adding dummy columns is unfortunately not an option as the ID can go up to 400.000...

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that. I think my edit should fix that. It matches rows of `DF` and `timetbl` by equal `ID` values.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! It is working now. When adding:`DFx[DFx == "NULL"] <- NA`  I got the result as wanted.